# Странная область видимости методов класса или вовсе класса в Yii

Tags: php, ооп, yii, область-видимости

В общем есть 2 сервера, на одном все работает а на другом пики... ну в общем суть проблемы:

На локальном хосте (запускаю через OpenServer, настройки пыха не трогал, пых 5.3, Yii 1.1.17) есть у меня некий файл Locale.php в котором обьявлен класс

```
class Locale extends CLocale.
```

В этом классе есть статичный метод `getInstance()`, к которому я обращаюсь из метода другого класса `NFormatter::getLocale()`

```
public static function getLocale()
    {
        CLocale::$dataPath = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'data';
        $locale = 'ru_ua';//Yii::app()->language;
        var_dump(Locale::getInstance($locale));
    }
```

На локальной машине метод `getInstance` виден и возвращает нужные мне данные, а на хостинге ошибка обращения к несуществующему методу. Для дебага
создал обьект класса, сделал дампы

```
$loc = new Locale($locale);

get_class($loc)
var_dump(get_object_vars($loc));
var_dump(method_exists($loc,'getInstance'));
```

Как только заливаю на хостинг  -  дамп пустой и `method_exists` возвращает false, хотя `get_class($loc)` показывает класс Locale.
То есть класс и там и там виден, но на хостинге почему то нет доступа к его методам.
Подозреваю что это все таки настройки сервера, что очень странно.

Comment: А у хостера что установлено? А права доступа и пути правильно указаны? `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($loc)));` ?

Comment: Права доступа перепроверил несколько раз так как это было первой версией, но с правами все хорошо. Пути все верные, иначе не видно было бы сам класс, но класс виден.
Дамп на локалке вернул `array(58) { [0]=> string(11) "__construct" [1]=> string(4) "init" [2]=> string(15) "setConfigNumber" [3]=> string(11) "getInstance"`+ методы класса родителя CLocale, на хостинге этот же дамп вернул только методы класса родителя CLocale.

Comment: Вот так будет лучше видно - (над ==== хостинг, под - локалка)
http://pastebin.com/tYSARBg6

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел причину. Спасибо E_p за подсказку вывести все методы, я увидел что методы которые возвращал дамп - не мои, полез гуглить и оказалось что класс Locale уже существует в php. Странно что пых ничего не написал насчет того что я пытаюсь обьявить уже существующий класс. Переназвал класс подругому и все заработало.

Мораль: Называйте классы с префиксами, иначе будет жопа.

Comment: В yii скорее всего авто загрузка. И если класс найден ничего не грузиться . Ну и надо переходить на актуальные версии PHP  и пользоваться  namespace